# How to add the data source to the rdlc file in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, desktop-application

I am new to windows desktop application development.

I want to generate a bill report that is the bill master details should be displayed once and the related items should be displayed in the tabular format.

I have created the data table in dataset. The data table is configured.

Now in the report design I am not able to see this table to drag the field to their proper position.

Please help how to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adding datasets**

First you have to add a `Data Source` in your Report. You can do this by using the `Data Sources` window in VS. Click the *Add new data source* and select what you want (I usually use object). In the `Report Data` window there is a folder '*Datasets*'. If you right-click it you can add a dataset.

**Data in a table**

To visualize the dataset you can drag a *Table* from your *Toolbox* onto the report, select it, then right-click on the upper-left corner and select `Tablix Properties`. There you can bind a Dataset to the table. Choose which items you want to display in which column by clicking on the column and selecting a value.

**Singular data (textbox)**

You can set an expression on a textbox that retrieves a specific set of data from a dataset (you can also use this on table columns btw). You can do this by right-clicking the textbox en going to `Expression`. This will open up an Expression window that contains some sort of expression builder.

The expression I use to retrieve singular data is the following (not sure if this is the best approach but it's the only one I know):

`First(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDatasetName")`

Basically I'm assuming there is only one row in my dataset (or that field is the same in all rows) so I'm just retrieving the first value.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.@Deruijter . Its working fine.

I want to display the data in the text box placed in the report design.

Comment: the Tablix Properties is available in the table only. How do I get that in the text box?

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain how I personally display singular data. It's not very elegant but I have yet to find a better solution (the alternative is working with Parameters but I haven't had time to try that out yet)